# Extracting Tweet ID from URL (Simple)

Tags: php, twitter

As an example, I have this URL:

```
https://twitter.com/VerizonWireless/status/412643303260446720
```

Using PHP how would one extract only the ID (412643303260446720) from it? Note that the `https://twitter.com/` will be the same each time however the rest will change.

Comment: [parse_url](http://www.php.net/parse_url) and [explode](http://www.php.net/explode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explode with / and take the last param:

```
<?php
$url = "https://twitter.com/VerizonWireless/status/412643303260446720";
$arr = explode("/", $url);
//echo $arr[count($arr)-1];
echo end($arr); //more clean
?>
```

Output:

```
412643303260446720
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/preg_match) to match all of the digits at the end of the line next to a slash:

```
$url = 'https://twitter.com/VerizonWireless/status/412643303260446720';

preg_match("/\/(\d+)\/?$/is", $url, $matches);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

The value in this case would be in `$matches[1]`.

Comment: Note that these status URLs can technically have a '/' at the end of them too, so this will not always work!